# Unstable requests on API - Not allowed

Tags: uber-api

I have an instability in the api requisitions. At times it is returned that the request was not authorized even with a valid token. Can you tell me what to do?

Comment: Is there an error message you can post?

Comment: From your other question, it seems like you are having issues with Uber for Business...perhaps follow up with your contact or at business-support@uber.com.  If you are going to ask a question on Stack Overflow, please provide technical details so people can help.